# SugarCRM Formula Builder

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I'm looking to create a new field called 'factored revenue'.

This is the formula I created which doesn't work

```
multiply(number($amount),number($opp_percentage_c))
```

As you can see I want an amount multiplied by a percentage but I'm really struggling to get this working; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I strongly recommend reading articles in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially those about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and creating good [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the field type for "opp_percentage_c"? When you say it "doesn't work", what happens? Is the syntax wrong? Does it give you a different number than you're expecting?